# How can I get the standard Age field on Case in custom report types?

Tags: custom-report-type

How can I get the standard Age field on Case in custom report types?  When i create a custom report type with Case as the primary ob,  the resulting report doesn't have the Age field as an available column in the report builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create your own custom field for this; if you go to the Customize screen and look at the Case fields you will not see one for `Age`. You can get further information on the Success boards on [case age reporting](https://success.salesforce.com/questiondetail?qId=a1X30000000HvtpEAC) and [is case age available on custom report types](https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000IsxhEAC).

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom formula field for the case object to calculate the case age then add that custom formula field to the custom report.